# Submit a form (sends email with data) and redirect to paypal page

Tags: forms, redirect, paypal, submit

I saw a few similar questions but they haven't been answered or they weren't exactly what I was looking.

I've got a short form on my webpage. When the 'submit' button is pressed the content on the form is send as email. Now I want to add the feature of re-directing the user to paypal page where they can pay admin fee.

Is there a way of adding some code to form's 'submit' button so that it redirects a customer to paypal check-out (as if they pressed 'buy it now') or alternatively, is there a way of making a custom 'but it now' button that will have a feature of submitting the form as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Set the variables below */

$contact_us = "contact-form";

$website_url = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/';
$error_page_url = $website_url . 'error.html';
$paypal_page_url = $website_url . 'paypalpageurl.html';
$dummy_email = 'no-reply@yourwebsite.com';
$receiver_email_id = 'me@yourwebsite.com';

/** WARNING !! Dont make changes below ***/

if(!empty($_REQUEST['uri'])){
    $uri=$_REQUEST['uri'];
}else{
    $uri='';
}


switch($uri){
    case $contact_us:
        contact();
        break;
    default:
        ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $website_url; ?>"><?php

}
function contact($request = "Contact Form"){

    global $error_page_url, $paypal_page_url, $dummy_email, $receiver_email_id,$website_url;

    $subject = "[yourwebsite.com] - Contact Form"; 
    $email = htmlentities($_REQUEST['email']);
    $name = htmlentities($_REQUEST['name']);
    $phone = htmlentities($_REQUEST['phone']);  
    $comment = htmlentities($_REQUEST['comment']);
    $filter = htmlentities($_REQUEST['filter']);
    $headers = "From:" . $dummy_email;
    $headers1 = "From:" . 'no-reply@yourwebsite.com'; 


    $formatted_message = "Request : " . $request . "\n" . "\n" .
                         "Sender Name : " . $name . "(" . $email . ")" . "\n" . "\n" .
                         "Email : " . $email . "\n" . "\n" .    
                         "Phone : " . $phone . "\n" . "\n" .                             
                         "Comment : " . "\n" . $comment . "\n" . "\n";
    $formatted_message_client = "Hi " . $name . ","."\n" . "\n" .
                                "Thanks for contacting us. We will get back to you soon." . "\n" . "\n" .
                                "Regards," . "\n" .
                                "yourwebsite.com Team";

        if($_POST['check'] != $_SESSION['check']) {
                session_destroy();
            ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $error_page_url; ?>"><?php
        }
        else {
            session_destroy();
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $error_page_url; ?>"><?php
            }
            else {
        if($name == '' or $email == '' or $phone == '' or $filter != ''){
        ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $error_page_url; ?>"><?php 
    }else{
        if( mail($receiver_email_id, $subject, $formatted_message, $headers1) &&  
            mail($email, $subject, $formatted_message_client, $headers)){
                    //session_destroy();
            ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $paypal_page_url; ?>"><?php
        }else{
            ?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<?php echo $error_page_url; ?>"><?php
        }
    }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, form submission is either via email or via HTTP.

You could try to fake something using JavaScript, but this is bound to break in curious and interesting ways, so the proper way to do it is to handle form submission from a CGI and return a redirection status code.